Regex \K escape sequence in Notepad++ does match what I target but can't replace the match
Bug or feature?
Example:
^(?:[^a-zA-Z\s\(]+)(?: · [^a-zA-Z\s\(]+)*\K[a-zA-Z]+ (?=(?:(?: · [^a-zA-Z\s\(]+[a-zA-Z]+ )* 【 [^ ]+(?: ·[^ ]+)* 】)?\r\n)


will match the transliterated parts "shibashiba", "dare" and "hakkiri" after the initial sequence of hiragana characters in these texts:
しばしばshibashiba  【 屡々 ·屡屡 ·屡 ·数数 ·数々 ·数 】
だれdare  · たれtare  · たta  【 誰 】
はっきりhakkiri


IMPORTANT: This website deletes consecutive space characters from any text if it's not in code blocks.
The original text has TWO spaces after each one of these parts:
しばしばshibashiba  
だれdare  
たれtare  
たta  

and it also deleted all trailing spaces, so it erased ONE space after
はっきりhakkiri 


Those parts are properly highlighted by the search.
When I attempt to replace the matched parts by anything, no replacement happens, and the search skips to the next match. Even if I attempt to replace by empty string.
All characters in the example are within the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane.
Do I misunderstand something?
I understand that I can't use a lookbehind
(?<=^(?:[^a-zA-Z\s\(]+)(?: · [^a-zA-Z\s\(]+)*)[a-zA-Z]+ (?=(?:(?: · [^a-zA-Z\s\(]+[a-zA-Z]+ )* 【 [^ ]+(?: ·[^ ]+)* 】)?\r\n)

because the part
^(?:[^a-zA-Z\s\(]+)(?: · [^a-zA-Z\s\(]+)*


is variable length.
Both the part discarded by \K and the lookahead after the match are necessary to avoid matching other lines of text. This pattern does match all variations I show above, and it also works well to avoid matching other parts of text, e.g. "(adv) often; again and again; frequently →Related words: 度々".

Example with surrounding text where the above regex successfully avoids all other lines except the 1st line of text, and it will match the 1st transliterated part:
しばしばshibashiba  【 屡々 ·屡屡 ·屡 ·数数 ·数々 ·数 】
(adv) often; again and again; frequently →Related words: 度々
あの木の枝に数羽の鳥がとまっている。
Some birds are sitting on the branch of that tree.

Notepad++ v8.6.5 (32-bit)

What exactly are you trying to match here?  Your question does not make this clear.

It is strange that I can't match hakkiri with your text and regex, but replacement is performed correctly (I can replace the first two words).

Can you please check and let know? I cannot reproduce the issue.

I just copied the text from here to a txt file and it doesn't match. This website erased some of the originally included space characters. I will edit the question and put those parts into code blocks. I hope that will preserve it as entered. I would have never expected that any such entry would be altered. It's not reasonable to automatically change an example text that is provided to check ANY question about parsing text.

Now edited the question. I wrapped the example texts in code blocks to preserve the example texts that are intended for parsing. I still find it baffling that someone came up with the idea to automatically erase parts of a question about parsing text.

Tim, the regex I included in the question is matching what I intend to erase (the transliterated parts "shibashiba", "dare" and "hakkiri") as I described in the question. The problem is not that it wouldn't match what I want. It does match exactly what I intend to match. But the issue is that when it matched those parts and they are selected, it's still impossible to replace them by the built in GUI for "find and replace". As I described, I attempted to replace by nothing (to erase the transliterated parts) to no avail.

Tim, now I added one example of surrounding text at the end of the question. This is just in case you want to see why the part before \K and the lookahead are necessary, to avoid matching other lines than the 1st in the complete text.

Wiktor, I'm sure hakkiri was not matched because the one trailing space after the word was erased automatically after I published the question. Now that it's in a code block, it will be possible to copy & paste it from here to a txt file.
